# googlemaps apiでルート検索を使って中継地点を設定したいのですが

Tags: api, google-maps

プレイスライブラリを使って範囲内に表示されたマーカーに自分だけのルートを検索できるようにしたいのですが、始点と終点は設定していのですが間の中継地点がうまく実装できません。そこでインフォウィンドを開いているマーカーに設定している名前か緯度経度をとってきてそれを中継地点に設定しようと考えています。

そこで選択されたマーカーの名前か緯度経度を取得方法を教えてください。もしあればよい方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

コードが無いので、どのように実装しているのか分かりませんが
`infowindow.position`で緯度経度オブジェクトが取れるので
`infowindow.position.lat()` & `infowindow.position.lng()`で取得できないでしょうか？